# Spring,Primefaces,Hibernate: Save action is called automatically when I hit the create url

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, save

I am trying to show a form and then save it. I am using Spring + primefaces and hibernate.

The problem is that when I try to hit URL `DRS/jsf/lodi/createLodi.xhtml`, I am expecting it to just show the form to create entity. But what actually is happening that it is first calling saveLodi() method and creates a record in database.

I don't know what is causing it to do so. 
Here is my createLodi() Method

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public String newLodi() {
    lodi = new Lodi();

    return "/jsf/lodi/createLodi.xhtml";
}
```

and here is saveLodi()

```
/**
 * Save an existing Lodi entity
 * 
 */
@Transactional
public String saveLodi(Lodi lodi) {
    System.out.println("SAVELODI CALLED...........!");
    lodiService.saveLodi(lodi);
    return "/jsf/lodi/listLodis.xhtml";
}
```

And I am calling it from a menuitem of menubar component like

```
    <p:menuitem value="Enter and Update 807's" url="#{LodiComponent.newLodi()}" ajax="true"/>
```

What is wrong with it? Why save is being called? Can anyone give me an idea?

Thanks,
Tahir

Comment: So tahir Do you mean to say that you are calling `newLodi(param)` but it invokes `saveLodi()`.Right?

Comment: It is invoking newLodi() but before coming to that form it automatically saves the new object in database, which I don't want. because this adds a blank object in database.

Comment: it means when you invoke saveLodi() then first it enters a blank object in DB and after then the other object(in which data is present)

Comment: I am not invoking saveLodi()...it is automatically being called.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an error with how your transactions are set up and or the flushmode you use.

The question is what happens between your createLodi and saveLodi method? When you make a Hibernate call to that entity or still have any other ongoing transaction a query or commit there might trigger a flush() when you have set it on flushmode.AUTO (which is default).

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

The clean solution would be to set up the transaction in a way that createLody and saveLodi are in one transaction. So hibernate will handle that the entity is only saved in the DB when the transaction is ended without any error or abort. Also this would enable you to set the transaction up exactly how you need it.

Comment: but why when I write: 
`new Lodi()`

it is trying to save in database as well ?

Comment: Well I can not really answer this from the information I have. For that I would need to know at what point exactly the entity is saved into the DB. Is it still during your readOnly transaction? How is your Hibernate configured? What other transactions or queries are taking place? Atm it should not create a DB entry during your newLodi() method. My guess is that the Entity is persisted when it is called from the /jsf/lodi/createLodi.xhtml. This is a query and with standard settings hibernate is flushing before most queries causing changes to be persisted in the DB.

Comment: I will try to get you more info shortly. BTW thanks a lot for helping :)